# How to convert GDataXMLElement object to NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, soap

I use `SOAP` service in my `iOS App`. I need to manage response from the service. I use `GDataXMLElement` as it in [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml) tutorial (see: **Converting the XML to our Model Objects**).

My problem is that I don't understand how to extract `NSArray` from `GDataXMLElement`.

**My code is:**

```
            // Services List
            NSArray *bulletinServicess = [consumerCredit elementsForName:@"Services"];
            if (bulletinServicess.count == 1) {
                GDataXMLElement *bltnServices = (GDataXMLElement *) [bulletinServicess objectAtIndex:0];
               ??? srv = (long)bltnServices.stringValue.integerValue; ???
            } else continue;
```

On the row with **???** I need to make convertion but I don't know how.

How to do that?

**REMARK:**

Line `?? srv = (long)bltnServices.stringValue.integerValue; ???` just show where  I need to make cast to `NSArray` and how I make it for `int` (in this case).

**EDIT:**

My `GDataXMLElement *bltnServices` returns (on `po`):

```
{type:1 name:Services xml:"<Services>(
        (
    )
)</Services>"}
```

When my actual `xml` is:

```
<Services>
    <long>5</long>
</Services>
```

I am using `sudzc.com` wrapper, which automatically generates for me methods for `SOAP`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the integer value to a NSNumber and then can put it in an array. Here is what you can do with you `bltnServices.stringValue.integerValue;` line:

```
NSMutableArray *srv = [NSMutableArray array];
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:bltnServices.stringValue.integerValue];
[src addObject:number];
```

Comment: Sorry, @Yuchen, but I think I don't explain well. My `GDataXMLElement *bltnServices` contains `NSArray`. I need to extract it. I put line `??? srv = (long)bltnServices.stringValue.integerValue; ???` just as an example where I need to make convertion. Inside I take similar row when I make convertion from `int`.

Comment: @new2ios, oh, this is actually related to the XML that you are working with. Could you post an example of the XML document that you get?